# Several collection formats for the same table in Hive

Tags: hive

I process data with two maps per records, one is ("&","=")-formatted (id=111&name=...), the other one is (";","=")-formatted.

Of course, I could :

- replace ";" by "&" in the data
- or define

  - one of them as MAP with "COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ..." specified at declaration
  - and treat the other map as STRING and parse it with str_to_map() at each query.

But isn't there any more elegant solution like **multiple collection format declaration** for the same table?

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about writing your own Writable and SerDe to create a table with 4 columns:

- String key1
- String value1
- String key2
- String value2

You could use this [example](http://pastebin.com/xUy36Kxg) as a starting point.